# BiqQuery SPLIT "Byte" column into rows

Tags: python, google-bigquery

I have a 2 columns bigquery table, one column is an INTEGER the other one is a BYTE column that stores a meaningful data per character (meaning every single character inside the column matters).

I need to generate **1 row per ID - Character inside BYTE column** combination.

I am using bigquery but I may be able to code some Python stuff as well.

Table details:

- Structure: 
  ID: INTEGER, 
  AVAIL: BYTE
- Avail column may contain up to 3500 characters
- Goal

#### id | avail

41 | 0 
41 | 1 
41 | f 
41 | f 
. 
.  
. 
.

- Table sample:

[image: table sample]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Below example for BigQuery Standard SQL

```
#standardSQL
with `project.dataset.table` as (
  select 1 id, b'01fff' avail union all
  select 2, b'07fff' union all
  select 3, b'3ff00f'
)
select id, 
  offset,
  chr(to_code_points(x)[offset(0)]) as avail
from `project.dataset.table`,
unnest(split(avail, b'')) x with offset
```

with output

[image]

Comment: Wow. A lot of new things to learn here! Thank you, Mikhail. I am getting some weird characters on the avail column, I will need to check my data type to be consistent on the byte data type for that column. I will mark this as the correct answer as it solved my problem. Thank you!

Comment: glad it helped :o)